# Write response error after closing a connection

Tags: http, go

`http.Response.Write` causes `'use of closed network connection'` error after the closing of the `net.Conn` what the `http.Response` has received data from. E.g. I need to do something like this:

```
func Do(req *http.Request) *http.Response {
    // ...

    req.Write(conn)

    var r = bufio.NewReader(conn)
    var resp = http.ReadResponse(r, req)
    conn.Close()

    return resp
}

//...
var resp = Do(req)
resp.Write(anotherConn) // here is the error
```

but the last line gives the above error. You can say that an obvious solution is the `conn.Close` after `resp.Write` but the reason of that I do like this is that `Do` must write the `req` to the `conn` that it creates itself and then only return the `resp`.

The only thing that interests me is that how the `conn` and the `req` are related. I thought that response saves all the received data in itself in `ReadResponse` and then does not depend on connection that it has received data from. But it does not seem like this.

Comment: I'm only guessing but the body of the response is probably read lazily from the connection, so if that's the case you could first read the whole body into some buffer then close the connection, then set the read body to the response's Body field, and then continue?

Comment: ... if you check the [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Response), it does seem to suggest that that *is* the case: *"The response body is **streamed on demand** as the Body field is read. "*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ReadResponse` reads the status line and headers, then exposes the response body in `Respons.Body`, which accesses the underlying connection directly to read the body on the fly, rather than loading the entire body (which could be many megabytes) into memory. This allows the implementation to be as efficient as possible, e.g. stream processing the body rather than loading all of it into memory and then processing it.

[Per the docs](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Response):

> The response body is streamed on demand as the Body field is read. If the network connection fails or the server terminates the response, Body.Read calls return an error.